# Is it possible with pure CSS, preferably compatible to version 2

Tags: css

I have a layout in a div comparable to the media files on a Hulu row.  Something like

```
*---------------*  *------------*  *------------*
|               |  |    Small   |  |    Small   |
|               |  |    Item A  |  |    Item B  |
|               |  *------------*  *------------*
|   Big Item    |
|               |  *------------*  *------------*
|               |  |    Small   |  |    Small   |
|               |  |    Item 1  |  |    Item 2  |
*---------------*  *------------*  *------------*
```

The problem here is the "order" of the items.

The order in the dom of the items would be A, B, 1, 2

However, You'll notice A and B are side by side, as are 1 and 2. What I *want* for A and B to be Stacked in column one, and then 1 and 2 and then any others etc...

Like so:

```
*---------------*  *------------*  *------------*
|               |  |    Small   |  |    Small   |
|               |  |    Item A  |  |    Item 1  |
|               |  *------------*  *------------*
|   Big Item    |
|               |  *------------*  *------------*
|               |  |    Small   |  |    Small   |
|               |  |    Item B  |  |    Item 2  |
*---------------*  *------------*  *------------*
```

The layout is in the HTML of:

```
<ul>
    <li>big item</li>
    <li>small item A</li>
    <li>small item B</li>
    <li>small item 1</li>
    <li>small item 2</li>
    ......
```

thus far, by making my UL a specific width, is how i've gotten the smaller items to stack, but like i said, I'd like for them to stack in order of placement in the DOM.

And no i don't have a fiddle, because this is part of a skin i'm customizing for jcarousel, and it's honestly harder to make a short fiddle of this example with my custom skin, and dynamic list items than it is to figure this problem out ... i think!

Which reminds me, all these li elements are added dynamicly from a controller. I suppose i could calculate and give each one a specific "top"|"bottom" class, but this is one thing I'm trying very hard to avoid! If i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the smallest bare minimum example with changed stacking order, no divs, only css.

http://jsfiddle.net/mm58g/

```
<ul>
    <li class="big">Big</li>
    <li class="small">Small A</li>
    <li class="small">Small 1</li>
    <li class="small">Small B</li>
    <li class="small">Small 2</li>
</ul>

ul{width:500px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
li{border:1px solid green;list-style-type:none;}
.big{width:150px;height:150px;float:left;}
.small{width:120px;height:65px;float:left;margin:0 0 20px 20px;}
```

Comment: i can't test at moment, but i'll try this out. your example looks great, ty!

Answer (score 2):

There is the possibility to insert all you items into a table to get them to the right position, just as you like. But this is a oldschool programming style that is not rly anymore in use. (You have to take care of min and max width's here because of different screen resolutions!)

Another option (and the best here) is to get your Big item into a div box and also A+1 and B+2 into divs too.
Float them side by side with a clear after the A+1 float and it will work I think.
(And dont forget the div arround all items ;) )

Second solution should be your choice, because you can easily get div solutions up on smartphones too and you will save tons of code you dont have to type down.

Hope it works, if you have issues with the div code to handle write me.

@Johan Bouveng!!! Yeah, you are right but this isnt a final solution, earlier or later he has to change it into div format. You wont find that kind of code in everday life.